# Who was the first scientist to develop the concept and mathematical formula of string theory?

Tags: string-theory

I was just looking at a YouTube Video interview with Leonard Susskind and did not realize he was the first to discover stings in string theory!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQAcLW6qdQY&pbjreload=

@12:30

It is an interesting video but I also had read a few articles of other participants in this endeavor such as Veneziano while working at  CERN  and others who were also working on the same idea so I did not think anyone person was really the originator but I believe I am wrong now. I believe he was the first to develop this.

I am wondering if someone is familiar enough with the topic to perhaps comment on the history of it's original founding?

Comment: I believe string theory grew out of the [S-Matrix Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix_theory) of Heisenberg (1943) via Wheeler (1937). However, it wasn't until 1970 that Susskind interpreted one aspect of the (by then, different) mathematical model as a one-dimensional vibrating string. The subject has such a dynamic history that it is hard to know where to focus.

Comment: I followed through the links provided by the first link of Nick R and as he points out  the history is so dynamic  that it would be difficult to trace.  There are different versions of the beginnings with different advantages to each with varying degrees of dependence.  But reading through the links is very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a collective effort, and certainly it is not one formula as the title of your question seems to imply:-)

One of the principal "founding fathers" was Gabriele Veneziano.